# Determine the weights in the minimum variance portfolio.

Tags: finance, variance

Consider three securities with the following expected returns, standard deviations of returns, and correlations between returns:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\mu_1=0.20, & \sigma_1=0.31, & \rho_{12}=\rho_{21}=-0.2, \\
\mu_2=0.25, & \sigma_2=0.17, & \rho_{23}=\rho_{32}=0.6, \\
\mu_3=0.17, & \sigma_3=0.27, & \rho_{31}=\rho_{31}=0.15, \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Determine the weights in the minimum variance portfolio.

My question is what is a minimum variance portfolio?
For finding the weights I know $0.20\omega_1+0.25\omega_2+0.17\omega_3=$ expected return of portfolio and $\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_3=1$ but I don't know what the expected return of the portfolio is and there are three variables but only 2 constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first form the covariance matrix, $C,$ its entries are found from the standard deviations and correlations.

Let $e = (1,1,\dots,1).$ In this case, $(1,1,1).$

Solve $Cy = e.$

Normalize the elements of $y$ so they add to $1.$

Done.

(for discussion of why this is the minimal variance portfolio, see Joshi--Paterson, Introduction to Mathematical Portfolio Theory.)

Comment: why does e equal the matrix $(1, 1, 1)$? So I know how to find the covariance (my professor taught us that the covariance matrix contains the variances down the main diagonal and the covariances in the other spots), all I have to do is solve for y? y is a 3x1 matrix and those values correspond to the weights correct?

Comment: Really 1,1,1 and not 0,0,0? cc @idknuttin

Comment: yes really (1,1,1). $y$ gives the proportions but you have to make them add to one. This result derived by taking the algorithm for finding the tangent portfolio and letting the risk-free rate go to minus infinity.

Comment: @MarkJoshi Any idea if this is related to PCA? I swear I did something like this for a statistics class. I think it involved singular value decomposition

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 securities $S_1, S_2, S_3$

$$E[\sum_i \omega_i S_i] = \sum_i \omega_i E[S_i]$$

$$Var(\sum_i \omega_i S_i) = \sum_i \omega_i^2 Var(S_i) + 2\sum_{i < j} \omega_i \omega_j Cov(S_i, S_j)$$

We want to [minimise](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/economicas/bdeblas/teaching/ucd/ecn134/lectures/mv_review.pdf) $Var(\sum_i \omega_i S_i)$.

For $j=1,2,3$, solve

$$0 = \frac{\partial Var(\sum_i \omega_i S_i)}{\partial \omega_i}$$

We thus have

$$0 = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \omega_i Cov(s_i,s_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \omega_i \sigma_i \sigma_j \rho_{i,j}$$

$$ \to 0 = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \omega_i \sigma_i \rho_{i,j}$$

This gives us $\Sigma \omega = 0$ where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix, $\omega$ is the vector of weights and $0$ is the zero vector.

To verify that it is a minimum, use second derivative test.

Comment: if $\sigma$ is positive definite this will give $0$ only!

Comment: @MarkJoshi Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @MarkJoshi that doesn't satisfy the sum to 1 constraint...?

Comment: so you will get no solutions satisfying the constraint!